# What does the OS exactly do, when there is not enough RAM or processor time?

Tags: operating-systems, kernel

I always thought, he would just give important processes all they need, and the others will be forced to wait. But how does he assign priority? What if i have 4gigs of ram, and 3 processes all with the same importance, each need one, how does the OS decide, who gets how much, who falls behind and who is a priority?

Comment: This is a complex problem which is somewhat OS dependent, and arguably to broad - have a read of https://www.cs.montana.edu/~chandrima.sarkar/AdvancedOS/CSCI560_Proj_main/   As far as memory goes, programs request what they need, and if they are not bounded, can consume all available memory, then swap, then cause an OOM (Out of memory) problem whereupon the OS kills it.

Comment: The answer is to long for here. A description of the Windows Scheduler can be read here. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Kernel-Internals/One-Windows-Kernel/ba-p/267142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAM is basically first-come first-serve. Depending on the OS and how memory management is implemented (overcommit, paging etc), the OS may be forced to kill processes (like the Linux OOM killer). Other than that, the process will simply be handed an error message when trying to allocate more memory than available.

CPU time is distributed according to the process/thread priority. There are two special cases: Realtime and Idle. A process with Realtime priority can actually lock up the system by using all CPU time – mouse and keyboard will stop working. A process with Idle will only run when no processes with higher priority require CPU time.

By default, some more critical processes have higher priority.